# longest_palindrome, expected 0, got nil, where should if-else statement?

Tags: ruby, palindrome

Taking on the CodeWar Challenge. Struggling to fix my code so that if the length of the string input is 0, it would show 0 instead of nil.

Code is below: (suggestions?)

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  i = 0
  a = []
  while !string[i..-1].empty?
   j = -1
  while !string[i..j].empty?
    s = string[i..j]
     if s.reverse == s
       a << s.length

         if s.length == nil
           a.max = 0
          end
     end
    j -= 1
    end
     i += 1
    end
 a.max
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to point out a couple of issues with the code you posted.

The body of the innermost if statement is **never** executed because

```
0 != nil
```

This means that even if s.length evaluates to zero

```
s.length == nil
```

will still be false.

Another issue I'd like to point out is that

```
a.max = 0
```

will throw an error that looks like this:

> undefined method `max=' for []:Array (repl):17:in`longest_palindrome'
>   (repl):1:in `initialize'

You can't set the max value directly. The reason you never run into this error with the code you posted is because of the first issue I outlined above.

Now to answer your question. There are a lot of ways to do what you are asking. For example, you could just check whether the input string is empty
at the beginning of the code and immediately return 0 if it is therefore
never executing the while loops at all. Maybe with something like

```
return 0 if string.empty?
```

at the beginning of the code.

But from your question, I think what you are looking is something more like the following:

```
def longest_palindrome(string)

  i = 0
  a = []

  while !string[i..-1].empty?
   j = -1
   while !string[i..j].empty?
    s = string[i..j]
    if s.reverse == s
       a << s.length
   end
   j -= 1
  end
     i += 1
 end

  a.max.to_i
end
```

Of interest here is the second last line which makes sure ***a.max*** is converted
to an integer using the ***to_i*** method. Calling this method on nil converts it to 0.
Also, please note I have changed the code to fix the issues I had highlighted earlier.